# Regexp doesn't work if used with match()

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why the following does not work?:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anderslyman/86NHs/

JavaScript:

```
var value = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
var wordLength = 11;
var find = new RegExp('\b[a-zA-Z]{2,' + wordLength + '}\b');
console.log(value.match(find));
console.log(value.match(/\b[a-zA-Z]{2,11}\b/));
```

I would expect both `console.log()` statements to output the same thing,  since the regular expressions are identical...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`\` already has special meaning in strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings), so you need to double-escape them.

```
var find = new RegExp('\\b[a-zA-Z]{2,' + wordLength + '}\\b');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/35Msf